# How do I determine the significant figures of a derived uncertainty?

Tags: statistics, physics

I have been given an arbitrary set of values with their respective (absolute) uncertainties.

I am to perform an arbitrary amount of arithmetic operations upon these values in order to ultimately obtain a derived value.

I have calculated the relative uncertainty of the  derived value. Now all that remains is to calculate the absolute uncertainty.

My derived value is rounded off to 3 signifiant figures. How does this rounding off relate to the significant figures of my absolute uncertainty?

Edit: The concerned set of values were obtained by experimental means.

Answer (score 0):

Your absolute uncertainty should have the same amount of decimal places as your derived value.